# Set up proper URL directory structure for web pages

Tags: php, html, web

Many websites use the following format for different pages throughout the site.

For example:
**http://www.state.nj.us/nj/**

The about page URL is:
**http://www.state.nj.us/nj/about/**

Currently my about page URL is **http://www.website.com/about.php**

The URL looks much cleaner and better using the the folder structure **website.com/about/**

I just wanted to figure out whats the proper way web developers set this up for their website for other pages.

Do they really make a **about** folder in the root directory and use a **index.php** for the about page? So whenever they open the **/about/** directory it automatically loads the **index.php** file for that particular page?

Thanks for any help just trying to use proper etiquette for my site

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not at all.. What we do is to use url rewriting...
[CHeck this](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2011/11/introduction-to-url-rewriting/)

Feel free to comment if u need help ;)..Coz I have also worked it out in the previous week
Create an .htaccess file in the dir you are working on and write:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule   ^about/?$   about.php  [NC]
RewriteRule   ^stories/?$   stories.php  [NC]
```

Comment: Thanks for replying! Never would've thought it was the .htaccess file that was actually making that URL